# What do you call someone who makes sausages?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm looking for the name of the person who makes sausages. As in, you have a butcher and [the guy makes the sausages].

Comment: The guy who makes [Danish salami](https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTsHFoxGuFBTqXO_RumJn8-P4VXLyZFqVumj2i0-6aX_ITdyLgh) probably wouldn't be the same guy that makes a [traditional British banger](https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR5WTUUpp582Wa4hMDkxak60hBRsRKwcX5LInYMHv3PrnOdzWx0Hg). They're both sausage-makers, but I doubt there's any other word that covers both.

Comment: One would be a Pølsemager the other a Sausage-maker, no?

Answer (score 1):

Salumist is the term that has (slowly) taken hold in the US for the makers of high-end charcuterie and sausages.  I cannot find a dictionary that refers to it. But, I'm seeing it more and more in publications.

The term is derived from the Italian "salumi".   Which has the same meaning as charcuterie in French and English, though it does include sausages (especially dried) in addition to cured meats.

Mario Batali's father (Armandino) is a noted salumist.  He owns a store named Salumi.

Alternatively, and probably more correctly there is the term Salumi Artisan.  Personally, I prefer this one because it is not a neologism twisted upon importation from a foreign language.

If you are not taking about a high-end maker, then typically most would call them either a sausage maker or butcher.

Comment: Many, if not most, _-isms_ and _-ists_ are “twisted upon importation from a foreign language”.

Comment: "Sausage maker" is the current most popular generic term in the US. In gastronomic circles, it'll be the French borrowed term 'charcutier'. 'Salumist' is very new.

Comment: @mitch I agree. Salumist is new.  And I've edited to clarify that this typically refers more to a high-end maker.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I agree. But, until I see it in a dictionary I tend to discount it as an incorrect or unofficial appropriation.  Especially in this case, because, the proper term in Italian is "salumiere" (although that does have a connotation of being a grocer, too.)

Comment: @mitch I don't know if I'm wrong, but charcutier tends to conjure images of cured meats over specifically sausages to my mind. Salumist can be accused of a similar transgression, but I tend to think of them making more sausages than a charcuterie.

Answer (score 1):

Since sausage is charcuterie, the person who makes it could be called a charcutia.

Comment: This would benefit from an authoritative reference.  Please take a moment for the [tour] and the [FAQ], and welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In Italy the traditional travelling pig butchers and sausage makers are the norcini - folklore has them as mystical such are their salumi skills.